# "Destination address required" when send message in other direction

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, boost-asio

I have client and server app. They use udp socket to communicate.

I can send some message from client side and receive it at server. But I can't send message in other direction.

I modify [client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_udp_echo_client.cpp) and [server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_udp_echo_server.cpp) boost example.

My server:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

enum { max_length = 1024 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cerr << "<port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        int port = std::atoi(argv[1]);
        udp::endpoint endpoint(udp::v4(), port);
        udp::socket *socket = new udp::socket(io_context, endpoint);

        std::cout << "starting loop\n";
        while(true) {
#ifdef GOOD_RIRECTION
            char data[max_length];
            size_t len = socket->receive(boost::asio::buffer(data, max_length));
            std::cout << "Recieved: "<< std::string(data, len) << '\n';
#else

            std::cout << "Enter message: ";
            char request[max_length];
            std::cin.getline(request, max_length);
            size_t request_length = std::strlen(request);
            socket->send(boost::asio::buffer(request, request_length));
#endif
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My client:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

enum { max_length = 1024 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 3) {
            std::cerr << "<host> <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        udp::socket *socket = new udp::socket(io_context);
        udp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        udp::resolver::results_type endpoints =  resolver.resolve(udp::v4(), argv[1], argv[2]);
        socket->connect(*endpoints.begin());

        std::cout << "starting loop\n";
        while (true) {
#ifdef GOOD_RIRECTION
            std::cout << "Enter message: ";
            char request[max_length];
            std::cin.getline(request, max_length);
            size_t request_length = std::strlen(request);
            socket->send(boost::asio::buffer(request, request_length));
#else

            char data[max_length];
            size_t len = socket->receive(boost::asio::buffer(data, max_length));
            std::cout << "Recieved: "<< std::string(data, len) << '\n';
#endif
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where `GOOD_RIRECTION` is defined everything works fine.

When it is not - I got `send: Destination address required` exception on first send.

As far as I understand sockets are direction independent so I do something during establish connection. But I can't understand what exactly.

**update:**
From comments I understand that there is no "connection" in udp.

I build my client twice (with and without `GOOD_RIRECTION` define).I tried use one to send message and another to receive. In such situation I didn't receive first message and got `send: Connection refused` on sending second message.

Comment: There is no connection in udp. Each and every message must have its destination explicitly stated (and it may be different for every message). *Also, messages may be lost, they may arrive out of order, they may even arrive twice, your application must be ready to handle that if you use udp.*

Comment: ok. It make sense. 
As I understand I need to use IPAddress on side that send message?

Comment: You do. Which means you must retrieve it, by using `receive_from` instead of `receive`. And then send the reply with `send_to` instead of `send`.

Comment: My telephone works when I receive calls...